# Names of myself?

Tags: reflexive-pronouns

If you omit the names of Mary and myself from the list...

1. Why is   names of 'myself'   possible?
2. And someone says it can be 'the names of Mary and me'.
   Can I use mine instead of me?

Comment: Araucaria’s answer on this question may be helpful: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/86000/its-difficult-organising-me-or-its-difficult-organising-myself?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

It is correct to say, "omit the names of Mary and me from the list." You could also say, "omit Mary's name and mine."

It is a common error to use "myself" (the reflexive pronoun) in place of "me" (the non-reflexive pronoun).

It is an error, possibly stemming from people wanting to sound more formal or fancy by using more syllables. I don't know.

Comment: if you took Mary out, that would leave *Omit the name of me from the list* ?

Comment: @Smock no, it wouldn't be correct to write or say that, but it wouldn't  be correct to say "omit the name of myself," or "omit the name of I" either. You would have to say, "omit my name" or, if the context of names was clear, "omit mine."