# Should it be "as me" or "as myself" in the following?

Tags: pronouns, reflexive-pronouns

> I'm sure I'll meet you again *as me/as myself*, not as a client.

(Meaning that their relationship was businesslike, and the speaker wants their relationship to be more personal the next time they meet.)

Should it be *as me* or *as myself* here? Why or why not?

Comment: There's a very good explanation of some general guidelines for using reflexive pronouns in an answer to ["It's difficult organising me" or "It's difficult organising myself"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/86000/9161) that might be helpful, although I don't think it directly answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm sure I'll meet you again as **myself**, not as a client* would be the best choice here (IMO), but I believe it is better to say:

*Hopefully next time I meet you, it shall be more casual...*